# Multiple seperator shows content in different ways

Tags: xpages

My content with a multiple seperator is shown in two different ways on different server. In the first way the content is shown perfectly, multiple values are shown on a new line. On the other server the seperator is shown as `<br>`. Here is my code: 
 
`<xp:inputText id="inputText9"readonly="true">
<xp:this.multipleSeparator><![CDATA[<br>]]></xp:this.multipleSeparator>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.QPrefs.MyHints[rowdata]}]]></xp:this.value></xp:inputText>`

 Has anybody an idea why my values are shown in different ways? The first server is a linux server and the second one windows. Both servers are on Domino 9.0.1 FP3.

Comment: Hej,
you probably misunderstood something, but Domino must be installed on some OS (windows/linux).
Please clarify what version of Domino servers you have and what OS they are installed on.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my mistake. The question is now updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally use \n as separator (and a text area) - and this works across Linux and Windows. So try this:

```
<xe:djTextarea id="inputfield" value="#{document.field}" multipleTrim="true">
    <xp:this.multipleSeparator><![CDATA[#{javascript:"\n"}]]></xp:this.multipleSeparator>
</xe:djTextarea>
```